# CircleGeometry to Shape

Tags: three.js, geometry, shapes

I would like to convert a THREE.CircleGeometry to a THREE.Shape, but I haven't found a way yet. I want to extrude this circle, but the ExtrudeGeometry() only works with shapes.

I know I can use curves to draw a circle but I want to keep the topology the CircleGeometry() gives.

If that's not possible, is there a work around to draw a circle shape which is made of a number of triangular segments that are oriented around a central point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a shape as circle geometry does.
Here is **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/tcLr7eg3/

```
var circleTri = new THREE.Shape();
radius = 30;
segments = 32;
var theta_next, x_next, y_next, j;
for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    theta = ((i + 1) / segments) * Math.PI * 2.0;
    x = radius * Math.cos(theta);
    y = radius * Math.sin(theta);
    j = i + 2;
    if( (j - 1) === segments ) j = 1;
    theta_next = (j / segments) * Math.PI * 2.0;
    x_next = radius * Math.cos(theta_next);
    y_next = radius * Math.sin(theta_next);
    circleTri.moveTo(0, 0);
    circleTri.lineTo(x, y);
    circleTri.lineTo(x_next, y_next);
    circleTri.lineTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone new to three.js looking to do this, you should try the [SphereGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry) shape. You can create a perfectly round sphere this way without the hassle of creating your own shape or trying to extrude a [CircleGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleGeometry) shape. The code example on the docs should give you a good starting point.

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );
```